# where is the source control->History menu going in xcode 9?

Tags: xcode

i just install the xcode 9 beta version , and i found that i can't see svn's all checkin logs in xcode 9 which are available in source control->History in xcode 8 and before , how to get these infomation  in xcode 9?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works for a git repository:

Open Menu View/Navigators/Show Source Control Navigator (%2)

Commit details appear in the Utilities pane if Source Control Inspector is selected.

Answer (score 39):

They moved it to this tab on the left nav.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Xcode Version 9.2

```
View -> Navigators -> Show Source Control Navigator
```

or just

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>